# How to force mount storage whetever corrupt or not?

Tags: external-sd, sd-card, storage, mount

I use my phone without back cover and I sometimes accidentally remove my Toshiba Exceria 32GB SDHC UHS-1

This time my phone keeps spewing out corrupt SD card and tries to make me format my already portable storage card.

I tried lsdsk but apparently Android doesn't have that command.

I successfully saved my files using an another android device that didn't give me any errors

Removing magisk plugin of "/media_rw sd card mount for apps because your nougat has sd card access issues on apps that doesn't have toggle for where to save thing etc" worked but I still would like to know how I can force mount SD cards/USB sticks.

Comment: There is no force mount but you can try to mount read-only (see [mount](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) --help)